# hide product tabs based on the product and user while

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer, tabs

I am using magento 1.8
I have multi store magento application.

I am adding custom attribute to the product, code is **product_creator_id**, Its nothing but a store id, that define the product is belongs to that store. I mean the product is created in that store.

I need to hide the product tabs while editing the product which is not belongs to that store.

**For example** 
If product-A is created in store-A then product-A is belongs to store-A.
If product-A is editing in store-A only then it has all the product Tabs visible.

If product-A is editing in store-B then only General tab visible rest of the tabs are hidden.

I have searched lot for this I got some event obsrever

```
controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after
core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after
```

etc.
I dont want to use these events because they executing for both front and backend event. Is their any event that execute observer method only when admin event call.
or else
any other idea to make it work.
Help me.

Thanks Lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got Solution...

Override the following file

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs
```

and near line number 162 or 192 before `return parent::_prepareLayout();`

just print the output

```
$tab_ids = $this->getTabsIds();
```

It will contain the all tabs id's, you can arrange $tab_ids ids as you needed. 
and pass it..

Thanks you